# Drag and sort test using Selenium web driver

Tags: java, jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I am trying to automate UI of a web page. Please find the link for the webpage below
http://demoqa.com/draggable/

In this web page we have an option called Draggable + Sortable .Click on Draggable + Sortable option. An un ordered list appears. List items can be dragged and we can re-arrange the order of this list.

I wrote a code to automate this . But my code is partially working. code is able to drag the element but unable to place it where I want.  please find the steps in the code.
I am trying to place One at the bottom of the list

```
WebElement drgnsort = dr.findElement(By.linkText("Draggable + Sortable"));
        drgnsort.click();
        WebElement container = dr.findElement(By.id("sortablebox"));
        List<WebElement> lis = container.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        WebElement one = lis.get(0);
        builder.clickAndHold(one).moveByOffset(0,200).release().perform();
```

Comment: The Actions class has a "dragAndDrop" feature.  You should look into using it instead of recreating the wheel.  ;)

Comment: In case of DragAndDrop I am unable to identify the destination location. The entire Unordered list is inside a a div and there is no other element except the unordered list. Please let me know if I am not clear

Comment: Then try "dragAndDropBy", it allows you to move it by pixel.

Answer (score 2):

Try following code:

```
Actions action = new Actions(we);
    List<WebElement> list = we.findElements(By.cssSelector("#sortablebox li"));
    WebElement target = list.get(0);
    WebElement dest = list.get(3);
    action.click(target).clickAndHold().moveToElement(dest).moveByOffset(0, 10).release().build().perform();
```

Where 'we' is instance of WebDriver.
You can Identify the un-ordered list by its index, we have to move element a bit more that is why I have used 'moveByOffset(0, 10)'.

Comment: Thank you Pankaj. Code works. I just have one question. Can you please explain cssSelector("#sortablebox li").  How is it different from locating the Un-ordered list with ID.

Comment: Can I also Know how get the "list" (List<WebElement>)  by using Id?

Comment: ID is unique throughout the page but if you have multiple webelement correspond to selector then use "we.findElements" instead of "we.findElement". You will get the list of webelements. P.S. if you found answer helpful then please upvote it. Thanks